# Differentiate the Langrangian function

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives

$$L=\frac{1}{2}w^T Σw+λ_1[E(rp)−w^Tμ]+λ_2[1−w^T1]$$

I want to calculate the derivative of the above function with respect to $w,$ $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w}$

the derivative of $\frac{\partial w^T Σw}{\partial w} =2Σw,$

the derivative of $w^T = \mathbb{I}$

i know the reuslt is:  $Σw−λ_1μ−λ_21$

but how it become this ? I am confused with matrix vector differentation.

Answer (score 0):

$$\Sigma w + \lambda_{1}[0-\mu]+\lambda_{2}[0-1] =\Sigma w - \lambda_{1}\mu - \lambda_{2}1 $$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).